# Eoan Ermine Ubuntu 19.10 update failure

Tags: boot

I have just Installed Eoan Ermine Ubuntu 19.10 from the Linus Format cover disc onto a system with AMD Phenom chipset 4GB RAM. After installing it there was a request to update Ubuntu which I accepted. It has a fast network connection direct to my hub. On rebooting it is taking 6+ hours to boot up and so far hasn't finished. Help please. I tried a completely fresh install but with the same result. I am a new Linux user with little programming experience.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Format magazine is bundled with disks containing software, but maybe Linux Format's Ubuntu .iso is not the official Ubuntu 19.10 .iso file which is available from the Ubuntu website. The MD5 calculation gives a checksum (called a hash value), which must equal the MD5 value of a correct ISO. The program md5sum is designed to verify data integrity using the MD5 (Message-Digest algorithm 5) 128-bit cryptographic hash. MD5 hashes used properly can confirm both file integrity and authenticity. Compare the hash (the alphanumeric string on left) that your machine calculated with the corresponding hash on the [UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) page.

It doesn't take very long to download an Ubuntu .iso file if you have a fast internet connection. I don't download the Ubuntu .iso file in a web browser. I download it from the terminal with `wget` using the `-c` option of `wget` to automatically resume the download if it is interrupted from the same place that it was interrupted until the download is finished.

```
-c
--continue
    Continue getting a partially-downloaded file. This is useful when
    you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of
    wget or by another program.
```

Comment: Many thanks. No sure that a checksum failure would explain the behaviour on the iso version (perhaps it would?) but my system seems stuck on the purple loading screen with the red and white dots continuing to change colour in order as if it was booting up but it has been doing that for over 2 hours so I suspect it is stuck again.  The original installation works fine, it is when I perform the update that the problems arise.

Comment: Have given up with Ubuntu 19.10 and gone to Xubuntu which has loaded OK but also not without a few problems however it is still usable, so thanks for your advice.